# Custom uninstalling clickonce application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, clickonce

Presently when i uninstall a .net clickonce app, it doesn't check whether the App is in the running state. Also it doesn't delete files on PC restart also.

So I am planning to overwrite the uninstall method to handle this situation.

Which is the class and method gets called on uninstall? `Inplacehostingmanager` class has only install related functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot implement the functionality for uninstall actions in your main application.
You need to overwrite the registry entries, written by the setup, to run a custom executable. This will then check if your application is still running and remove the files that you might have stored in a custom application folder. Then you call the real ClickOnce uninstall routine and you're done.

A very good tutorial can be found on [www.codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/506162/ClickOnce-application-autostart-and-clean-uninstal).